# z-index won't work internet explorer

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, z-index

I've been busy building a website for a DJ.
The header has a :before element on bottom of it. This has to be on top of everything, so I gave it the highest z-index.
On one of the pages i've included a youtube video.
This gives no problems in all of the browsers exept internet explorer.
The youtube video overlaps the :before element of the header.
The youtube video also overlaps the popup contact forms of the page.

I've searched for answers and found some jQuery scripts, but it didn't seem to work.
The page that's got this problem is http://leber.d7.cosly.com/nl/gigs/

Could anyone please help me fix this IE problem?

Answer (score 2):

When embedding flash you need to use a `wmode` of `transparent` or `opaque` for it to behave correctly with `z-index`. For youtube embeds you can do this by adding `wmode=transparent` to the query string:

```
<iframe src="http://youtube.com?v=YOUTUBEID&wmode=transparent"></iframe>
```

Comment: That is correct indeed. I had the same issue a few days ago, here is a working sample.. https://www.ordereze.com/holidaypromo/ - try clicking the sign up button to launch the popup.